# How can I make particles rise softly?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to make particles rise softly, as if floating on hot air. I've added drag, increased particle mass, and lowered wind strength, but it isn't getting slow enough.

Is this just a matter of finesse (right wind strength/particle mass), or is there a trick to it or a certain setting necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using wind etc. to blow the particles upwards, try disabling gravity for just the particles:

[image]

In this case the emitter plane's normal is facing upwards, so the particles start with a initial upwards motion.

I've also added a turbulence force field along with some random initial and brownian velocity, to give it a bit of randomness.

[image]

Comment: That's why you're the #1 user on Blender.SE ;)